# Display TextField at the top of Keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This is how my ViewController looks like in Storyboard:

[image]

```
@interface SettingViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSURLConnectionDelegate> { }
```

I found an answer by Shiun in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present). but that is not exactly what I am looking for.

Sometimes this Text Field become disappear behind the keyboard.

When I click on the textField and keyboard pops up :

I want the TextField to be visible at the top of keyboard.

I could not find any proper solution until now. Could you help me?

Comment: What do you want different from the link you reference?

Comment: As I written at the end of my question : I want the TextField become visible at the top of the keyboard.

Comment: Use the approach in the link you reference. Then scroll the scroll view so the text field is positioned just above the keyboard.

Comment: How can I scroll the scrollView? could you please share your answer.

Comment: I have a TextField in my custom cell. I do not know how to use `activeField`. for me it is cell.editText in the TableView. Do you know how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way of doing this. You will have to listen to keyboard notifications and then move the text field above the keyboard by finding the height of the keyboard.

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: Can I use this code in the CustomTableViewCell? otherwise how can I use activeField?

Comment: Yes, you can replace activeField with your customTableViewCell. You might want to have an activeTableViewCell property in your class and set this in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.